# Recursively get strings from array columns

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have an array of objects. Content of each array element can be String, or it can again be another array with strings. Or it can be again array of  arrays that hold strings.

Example:

```
Object obj1 = array[[str1, str2, str3], [str4, str5]] 

or: Object obj2 =array [str1, str2]

or: Object obj3 = "this string"
```

I need a method which takes this object as argument, and if it is one of first 2 cases, returns single array with those elements. And if it is a last case, it returns array with single string element that came in as param.

So, if i do

```
getDataForColumn(obj1) i get array: [str1, str2. str3....str5]
getDataForColumn(obj2) i get array: [str1, str2] //same as input, i know
getDataForColumn(obj3) i get array: ["this string"]
```

I am trying, but I really can not wrap my head how to do this with recursion, nor is it possible, well at least in this way.

This is what I came up with, and stuck.

```
private static Object[] getDataForColumn(Object column) {

if(column instanceof Object[]){
    Object[] castarray = (Object[])column;
        Object[]newArray = new Object[castArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < castarray.length; i++) {

              if((castarray[i] instanceof Object[])){
                 //recursion, but how :D    
                  }
               else{
                        newArray[i] = castArray[i];     
        }
    }
      return newArray;
   }    
 return new array with object that came in.....
}
```

Please help.
Thanx

Comment: What language is this, C#?  Oh wait... instanceof isn't a C# keyword ... perhaps Java?

Comment: can you please add an example? I don't think I understood what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple one to do it. I use List because I prefer it on arrays, but of course you can make a wrapper that will convert it to array in the end:

```
public static List<String> flat(Object o)
{
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (o.getClass().isArray())
    {
        Object[] oarr = (Object[]) o;
        for (Object obj : oarr)
        {
            strings.addAll(flat(obj));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        strings.add(o.toString());
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use an ArrayList to sequentially add all the flattened arrays together. You could have created one Array merging the current "result"-Array and the Array returned by the recursive call but using the ArrayList makes it easier. This way you don't have to iterate both Arrays and put them together in one Array.

```
private static Object[] getDataForColumn(Object column) {
ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

if(column instanceof Object[]){

    Object[] castarray = (Object[])column;

    for (int i = 0; i < castarray.length; i++) {

          if((castarray[i] instanceof Object[])){
             results.addAll(Arrays.asList(getDataForColumn(castarray[i])))    
           }
           else{
             results.add(castarray[i]);    
           }
    }
    return results.toArray();
}
```

I did not test this but i think that should work!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
getDataFromColumn(Object column) {
  List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
  recGetData(column,list);
  return list.toArray();
}
public void recGetData(Object column,List<String> list) {
  if (column instanceof String) {
     list.add((String)column);
  } else {
     for (Object o : (Object[])column) { 
      recGetData(o,list);
     }
  }
}
```

hope that what you meant.

 didn't test it yet, but should work....

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible,  maybe not the best way.

```
private static Object[] getDataForColumn(Object column) {
    if(column instanceof Object[]){
       Object[] castarray = (Object[])column;
       Object[] newArray = new Object[castArray.length];

       for (int i = 0; i < castarray.length; i++) {
          newArray[i] = getDataForColumn(castarray[i]);
       }

    } else {
       String[] newArray = {column};
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

I didn't test it, but I hope that will give you the idea

Comment: That one won't work, because the call to newArray[i] = getDataForColumn(castarray[i]); will put an Array into the newArray. That will not flatten it to one Array of Strings i think. (Testing it on paper, didn't work). Assuming you put an array like [a,b,[c,d]] initial in to the method. The result will be just a copy of that array.